# REST analog of SP.Utilities.Utility.formatDateTime

Tags: rest, csom, sharepont

I would be very glad if someone help me, I am trying to find REST analog of [SP.Utilities.Utility.formatDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411964(v=office.14).aspx) function:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var date = SP.Utilities.Utility.formatDateTime(context, web, new Date(), SP.Utilities.DateTimeFormat.DateTime);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() { console.log(date);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, according to this MSDN page it should be possible:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292556.aspx

However, I have yet to figure out what to send in as the first 2 parameters (context, web).

The request should look something like this:
https://testsite.sharepoint.com/subsite/**_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.formatDateTime**(???,???,'2005-5-5',1)

if anyone can help crack this even more - would be greatly appreciated.

I hope this is at least a part of the answer.